# how to make boost::asio::serial_port_base::flow_control use hardware flow control?

Tags: c++, boost, serial-port, boost-asio

Im wondering how do i enable hardware flow control on boost::asio::serial_port correctly!
Now i try to set this option after I open the Port using

```
serial_.set_option(boost::asio::serial_port_base::flow_control(boost::asio::serial_port_base::flow_control::none));
```

However, if I run the program I get an error telling me:

`set_option: Operation not supported on socket`

This isn't a very helpful message for me, since the chip should theoretically support hardware flow control.

Is there something I'm might missing or doing wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To enable hardware flow control, one must use the [`serial_port_base::flow_control::hardware`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/serial_port_base__flow_control/type.html) value for the `flow_control` option:

```cpp
serial_port.set_option(boost::asio::serial_port::flow_control(
  boost::asio::serial_port::flow_control::hardware));
```

If an exception is raised that the operation is not supported, then either:

- the hardware does not support hardware flow control
- the virtual serial port does not support hardware flow control
- Boost.Asio does not know how to enable hardware flow control for the detected system.  For non-Windows/cygwin configurations, this [snippet](https://github.com/boostorg/asio/blob/e818f88f/include/boost/asio/impl/serial_port_base.ipp#L267-L278) shows that only `_BSD_SOURCE` and `__QNXNTO__` configurations are supported.